# Доступ к документу во фрейме

Tags: html, iframe, dom

iframe достал уже. Не могу обратиться к его дереву с родительского скрипта!

```
iframe = window.frames[0]; 
elems = iframe.document.getElementsByTagName('*');
console.log(elems)
```

Показывает, что в документе фрейма только три узла - html, head, body.
Остального - скрипты, дивы, абзацы и т.д. - НЕТ. Документ ПУСТОЙ. Я никак не могу въехать в это дело. Помогите, плз!

Comment: Выложите код на jsFiddle.net

Comment: Код большой и конструкции взаимосвязаны. Могу только сказать, что в iframe сам ресурс src  генерируется автоматически. 
При этом если я пропишу 
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
то все прекрасно работает - выводит все узлы дерева, а для iframe - не хочет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё работает: http://jsfiddle.net/d9vcd/.

Comment: @lampa, да, все работает, но вставьте в body какой-нибудь див, и вы убедитесь, что console.log его не замечает

Comment: сори, мой косяк. Вот держите: http://jsfiddle.net/d9vcd/1/

Забыл добавить, посмотреть DOM iframe'а можно только в том случае, если домен в окне = домену, где расположено окно.

Comment: Класс, у вас все работает! А у меня нет. Наверное потому что "если домен в окне = домену, где расположено окно"? У меня все файлы расположены в одном каталоге.